# Bug Carousel Bootstrap 5.3 on iOS

Tags: html, ios, carousel, bootstrap-5, rounded-corners

I have a carousel of bootstrap 5.3 and i use the class "rounded-4" to round the corners of the carousel. On every pc and mobile the carousel is perfect but on iOS the rounded corners is broken. When the carousel slide the corners becomes edgy and after it return rounded
This is my corousel:

Image:[Carousel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbgCJ.jpg)
[Corousel sliding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRTV9.jpg)

```
<div id="slideShow" class="carousel slide draggable bg-dark rounded-4" data-bs-ride="carousel" data-bs-pause="false">
    <div class="carousel-indicators">
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#slideShow" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#slideShow" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#slideShow" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-inner rounded-4">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="img/IMG_1.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="img/IMG_2.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="img/IMG_3.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#slideShow" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
    </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#slideShow" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

i dont know what to try because the problem is presenting only on iOS